# How to Install DevExpress VCL components for delphi?

Tags: delphi, devexpress

I am having "DeveloperExpressVCLProducts.exe". I want to configure it with delphi 5 so that i can build the previous projects which uses DevExpress components. 
But I am unaware about how to install and where (at which path) to install. Please help me regarding this.

Thanks in advance for help.

Regards,

Naren

Comment: the installer does not have a readme file with instructions?

Comment: Did you not keep a complete copy of all your sources for your project? I never keep my "component installs" separate from my apps. The whole thing is checked into version control.  My install process consists of opening a project group and installing the designtime components with a few clicks.   Voila.   No more "reinstall all my components and find what versions to use" problems.

Comment: Actually I recently joined to project and there is no such document which contains installing part.. :( thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Only thing of importance is that you need [build 1.27](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q20473.aspx) to be able to install for Delphi5.
Other than that, it is simply executing the installer and following a wizard.

> You can continue using Build 27,
>   however, we cannot guarantee that this
>   will be able to apply code fixes
>   designed for newer builds of our
>   components to the libraries from this
>   build. From our point of view, it is
>   best to migrate to a newer version of
>   Delphi if you wish to use the latest
>   versions of our components.

Comment: I installed the components but while opening form I am facing "TdxBarManager.AllowReset property doesnot exist"

Comment: It just tells you a property no longer exists - you can go on. It can happen if you're using a different version than the code used.

Comment: but due to that i m unable to see form. . :( any solution to this.. thanks for help..

Comment: @Naren, you'll have to find out with what version of DevExpress your code was compiled. Perhaps easiest to drop them a mail asking what version contained the property AllowReset.

Comment: Thnaks 4 reply. Actually the component TdxBarManager class contains the property AllowReset. but still its saying property not found.. :(

Comment: How to install that DxBarManager component?? Which package contains that component?? anyone having ieda?? Plz help.

Comment: @Naren, I have had my share of bad experiences installing and/or upgrading components. Most of the time, it was my own lack of structure that got me into a mess, sometimes it was the suite. In the end, probably the fastest route to go is to reinstall from scratch (VM anyone?) and take a structured approach. 1. Install Component - Test - Document - Goto 1.

Comment: @Naren: Did you select "Ignore" or "Cancel"? If you select cancel you may not be able to see the form. If you select "Ignore" it should remove the property value from the dfm and open the form.
DevEx always came with an installer that takes care of installing the libraries properly - just run it  (although in some old version there could have been issue due to different libraries containing the same units but different releases). You may search here to find advices about how to organize your libraries.

Comment: thanks a lot for help.. I re-installed the devEx and the problem got resolved.. :)